# Using .bind() with events in classes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want objects to react to events, with their own methods.  I use bind to achieve this, for example:

```
class Class {
    constructor(something) {
        this.property = "foo";
        something.on('event', this.eventListener().bind(this));
    }

    eventListener() {
        this.property = "bar";
    }
}
```

Using bind everytime I do this feels strange, is this the best practice, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: well thats not the way to bind things. you should not execute the method `this.eventListener.bind()` would be correct. however, `this` refers to the instance so i dont understand why you want to bind it

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, fixed it now

Comment: We've had arrow functions for a while now: there is literally no reason to use `bind` anymore: `something.on('event', evt => this.handleEvent(evt))` and we're done. That's literally the reason _why_ arrow functions exist: to make sure `this` points to the right thing.

Comment: It's `this.eventListener.bind(this)` not `this.eventListener().bind(this)`, but otherwise fine.